# Subdomains on Windows Azure

Tags: subdomain, azure

I've got a Windows Azure project I'm working on. It has two web roles - one is a public-facing  site, and the second is an administration site for my customer to make changes to the database etc.

I had expected to be able to use a subdomain for each role - so for example have mysite.com and admin.mysite.com (obviously CNAME-mapped to the .cloudapp.net DNS name). However it looks like Azure doesn't do this, and instead has one subdomain (mysite.com) with different ports for each web role. So, for example, I would have mysite.com:80 for the main public site, and mysite.com:8080 for the administration.

Is this correct? Is there no way I can have subdomains for particular web roles?

Thanks in advance

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct.  You can, of course, respond to both subdomains in a single role.  But multiple web roles in Windows Azure correspond to multiple ports on the same virtual IP address.

Comment: Thanks - that's very useful (albeit not what I wanted to hear)!